# How to use RegisterPostBackControl() method of the ScriptManager with Frame which showing data after click on linkbutton in another .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I was trying to perform click evnet of the linkbutton in gridview and this grid view is in UpdatePanel control. I want to display Information/data on clicking on linkbutton in frame on the same page. But frame displaying another .aspx page.

```
protected void gvEditInvoice_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{  

    try
     {
          if (e.CommandName.ToUpper().Contains("LINKCLICK"))
          {                    

               GridViewRow gvr = ((Control)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
               int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(gvr.RowIndex);

               LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton)gvEditInvoice.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("lnbtnBillingEntityName");//.PostBackUrl = "~/somewhere/" + Session["path"].ToString();                    
               ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(lbtn);
           //RegisterPostBackControl() methods is used to postback full page after linkbutton clicked

               string urlPath = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); //.aspx Page URL is getting from field
           mainFrame.Attributes["src"] = @"/eis/IMS/WebUI/Prototype/" + urlPath;
           //mainFrame is my frame and showing another .aspx in this area of same .aspx page
           }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      }
}
```

Everying is going fine, But problem is that I have to click linkbutton twice, 
only then I am getting the result.
Could you please help me out in this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

add row data bound event as below and remove `RegisterPostBackControl` from row command event

```
protected void gvEditInvoice_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
   LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("lnbtnBillingEntityName") as LinkButton;  
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting GetCurrent() method of ScriptManager in intellnace.

Comment: Are you using an AjaxControlToolkit-ScriptManager?

Comment: No, I am using AJAX Extension ScriptManager